Why would this character keep fighting?
As this question refers to events from the finale of the series (or at least, its first season), I feel unable to selectively hide the spoilers as this would barely leave any content intact. Proceed at your own risk.
SPOILERS
SPOILERS
SPOILERS
In the (1st season) finale of Memories of the Alhambra, it is assumed that Jin-Woo is dead - he has somehow been entirely transferred into the game world, where Emma has identified him as an error and successfully removed him with the Key to Heaven.
In the end, however, it is revealed that Jin-Woo is indeed very much alive in the restarted game and uses his gun to support the regular players in their fighting. Hee-joo learns about this because she overhears other players talk about a mysterious advanced player with guns (which, based on what was shown before, can only be Jin-Woo).
But why would he be doing this?

At this point, the game is available on the market and used by many players. It can be assumed the errors have been ironed out and the attacks by NPCs are not directly dangerous to other players. Hence, there is no need to "protect" those players.
As the entire point of the game seems to be to increase your score, mostly by fighting, killing off attackers actually deprives players from good opportunities to gather these points. He's not exactly doing the players a favour by his interference.
Or is Jin-Woo himself still farming for points? Does he have to, even though he is a "master" (which appears to mean something like in-game admin)?

